# Jekyll: Displaying posts of different categories

Tags: markdown, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I have two different categories of posts, namely `blog_posts` and `notes` in my Jekyll-powered personal blog, and I'm trying to display posts of both categories separately under different permalinks, for example: `/blog/link-of-post-one` and `/notes/link-of-post-two`. This is the current file hierarchy:

```
-blog
--index.html

-notes
--index.html

-blog_posts
--_posts
--- 2018-06-07-link-of-post-one.md

-notes_posts
--_posts
--- 2018-06-07-link-of-post-two.md

-index.html

-_config.yml
```

_config.yml

```
name: Personal Blog
markdown: kramdown
permalink: /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title
```

/blog/index.html

```
---
layout: default
title: Blog posts
---
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <ul class="posts">

      {% for post in site.categories.blog_posts %}
        <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> » <a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Now, I was expecting a list of all posts under the category `blog_posts` to be displayed under the `/blog` link after the above configurations and code. However, no posts are currently rendered from the `/blog/index.html` file.

Running the `jekyll build` command from root path gives out this as the output:

```
Configuration file: /root_path/_config.yml
            Source: /root_path
       Destination: /root_path/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.03 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

What seems to be wrong with my configuration and code?

Comment: Maybe your posts are considered to be in the "future", thus not printed. If you retry it now, it might work.

Comment: @DavidJacquel The posts aren't displayed now either.

Comment: And what is the output of `{% for c in site.categories %}{{ c | inspect }}{% endfor %}`